# Enviar array multidimensional de PHP a jQuery (¿ajax?)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Si tengo un array en PHP:

```
$items = array(
  "nombtre" => "botella";
  "precio" => "1";
  "descripccion" = "Botella de cristal"
);
```

¿Cómo lo puedo mandar a *jquery* para utilizar todos los index del mismo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para declarar un array multi dimensional en JavaScript a partir de datos de una variable de PHP lo mejor es generar el código necesario (en el documento HTML) para definir su valor usando la función [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode):

```
<?php
$prueba = [
  'valor1',
  [
    'valor2.1',
    'valor2.2',
  ],
  [
    'indice3.1' => 'valor3.1',
    'indice3.2' => 'valor3.2',
  ],
];
?><script type="text/javascript">
var prueba = <?= json_encode($prueba,
  JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_APOS
) ?>;
console.log(prueba);
</script>
```

Ten en cuenta que si una matriz es asociativa, se convertirá en un objeto en vez de una matriz. En el tercer valor de mi matriz de ejemplo podrás observar ese efecto.

Aunque la seguridad de la función `json_encode()` suele ser suficiente, una mala implementación en el navegador o que cambiaran el modo por defecto podría ser un problema, por lo que es recomendable hacer uso de las opciones `JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_APOS`. Sin estas opciones `</script>` sería convertido en `<\/script>` y con ellas se convertiría en `\u003C\/script\u003E`.

---

Edito: Bueno, al final he visto que no estás hablando de una matriz multi dimensional, si no de una matriz asociativa (justo lo que te comentaba al final de mi respuesta original).

Aquí tienes el código exacto para el ejemplo que propones con sintaxis, pero no ortografía, corregida:

```
<?php
$prueba = [
  'nombtre' => 'botella',
  'precio' => '1',
  'descripccion' => 'Botella de cristal',
];
?><script type="text/javascript">
var prueba = <?= json_encode($prueba,
  JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_APOS
) ?>;
console.log(prueba);
</script>
```

Si lo que quieres es usar únicamente los índices (queda algo confuso el sentido de tu pregunta "para utilizar todos los index del mismo?") habría que usar [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/array_keys):

```
<?php
$prueba = [
  'nombtre' => 'botella',
  'precio' => '1',
  'descripccion' => 'Botella de cristal',
];
?><script type="text/javascript">
var prueba = <?= json_encode($prueba,
  JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_APOS
) ?>;
console.log(prueba);
</script>
```

Espero que estos dos últimos ejemplos satisfagan todas las preguntas que planteas.

Comment: Lo de los indices... que yo pueda buscar por nombre, pero al seleccionar el nombre que que automaticamente pueda trabajar los valores de los otros indices. De todos modos he creado una sala de chat, pero no sé cómo invitarte a ella. es esta : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133446/jquery Para poder discutirlo en privado ya que es una consulta bastante concreta... Y dudo que nadie más tenga esta misma duda.

Comment: ¿Se solucionó el problema?

Comment: Si señor, se me olvidó aceptar la respuesta. Gracias-

Answer (score 2):

Dado que PHP se ejecuta en el servidor y javascript en el cliente, no puedes "enviarlo" en el uso más estricto de la palabra.

Pero hay formas de poder usarlo:

```
 <script>
 <?php 

     $items = array(
         "nombtre" => "botella",
         "precio" => "1",
         "descripccion" => "Botella de cristal"
     );

     echo "var items " . json_encode($items);

 ?>

 console.log(items);

 </script>
```

Esta es una de las muchas maneras que tienes de hacerlo, simplemente "dibuja" la información en el lugar y con el formato adecuado.

Este código es solo a efectos ilustrativos, y es muy mejorable.

Ten cuidado también en cómo defines tus arrays, el separador de elementos es la coma ",", no el punto y coma ";".